# Tesseract searchable pdf creation doesn't work

Tags: pdf, tesseract

i'm running Tesseract 4.0.0 and i tried the following command in order to create a searchable pdf but it doesn't seem to work :

```
tesseract input output pdf
```

It gives an error :

```
can't open file "\Program Files\...//pdf.ttf"!  
error during processing
```

The pdf file gets created but it cannot be open.
I tried it on different image formats : jpg, tif, png with no success.

Answer (score 0):

It does work, not sure which os you are using, but I realised that to make it work on Linux a full install was necessary

```
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr-all
```

then, for a German document for example, originally a multipage tif:

```
tesseract multipage-tiff.tif out pdf -l deu
```

the manual is useful - https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki